# Why is there a memory leak with Firebug enabled?

Tags: memory-leaks, firebug

I have a couple of charts that I created using Highcharts. These are live charts. And to update these charts regularly I am using Primefaces' `RemoteCommand` components with recursive `setTimout`.

Now, if I turn firebug off and load the page, the memory usage stays around 105MB. But if I leave firebug on and load the page, then the memory usage keeps increasing. It reaches 500MB in just about 10 minutes.

At first I was thinking that the problem was either with Highcharts, Primefaces, or my own code. But now I know that it's because of firebug.

Why does it happen when the firebug is on?

Comment: Totally possible that firebug memory leaks. [Mozilla is notorious for often hemorrhaging memory in their apps.](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1006&bih=575&q=firefox+memory+leak&oq=firefox+memor&aq=0&aqi=g10&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=908l2223l0l2856l13l9l0l1l1l0l106l672l7.1l8l0)

Answer (score 1):

The Net tab has been notorious for introducing memory leaks. Try disabling it. You may see an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not leaking memory, but it's just consuming a lot of resources. It's written in JavaScript, so you can't expect quite of performance here. It injects itself into Firefox to provide additional functionality. The larger the site (in terms of client-side code and complexity), the larger Firebug's footprint gets.

Comment: It's been while but let me explain what happened. I was using Highcharts to create a live chart. And to update the live chart every 3 seconds, I used setTimeout function that invoked a PrimeFaces' remoteCommand component to send Ajax request to the server. At first, I suspected Highcharts, then Primefaces. Both of them handle that pretty good. It took me a while to find out that it was actually because the Firebug on my browser was on. As soon as I turned it off, the memory usage stop increasing. You can try that out.